# Azure DevOps run pipeline every 3 weeks

Tags: cron, azure-pipelines

I need to run the azure pipeline every 3 weeks. Have any idea how to implement that?

It seems that there is only a way to run it every 3rd week every month which is not my requirement.

Comment: What cron expression are you using? Did a cron expression for "every 3 weeks" not work?

Comment: Cron expression for "every 3 weeks" is actually what I am asking for. If there is one - please, share it to me.

Answer (score 0):

I might be late, but I answered a similar question in another post just now [Azure devops pipeline cron trigger to run pipeline once every four weeks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76529910/azure-devops-pipeline-cron-trigger-to-run-pipeline-once-every-four-weeks/77461609#77461609)

I assume that in your case you would have to run something like this:

```
trigger: none

## At 12:00 UTC every 3rd Monday
schedules:
  - cron: "0 12 * * Mon/3"
    branches:
      include:
        - master
    always: true
```