# Azure devops pipeline cron trigger to run pipeline once every four weeks

Tags: azure-devops, cron, azure-pipelines-yaml

I need to run an azure pipeline once every 4 weeks. I can see examples to run on the 4th week of every month but no references to run pipeline once every 4 weeks.

Can you help me in creating an azure pipeline cron that will run once every 4 weeks?

Answer (score 0):

According to the wiki at https://github.com/atifaziz/NCrontab/wiki/Crontab-Expression you would have to do something like this:

```
trigger: none

## At 12:00 UTC every 4th Monday
schedules:
  - cron: "0 12 * * Mon/4"
    branches:
      include:
        - master
    always: true
```

The Mon/4 says that you want to run the pipeline every 4th Monday

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this would mean the pipeline runs on every 4th monday of the month. I need to run the pipeline once every 4 weeks. So if a month has 5 weeks then the pipeline should run at 3rd week next month. Hope this clarifies